# Rest post with json using ansible

Tags: ansible, python-requests

I am trying to post a JSON test to Cisco ACI.
The test is to create a tenant from the JSON using REST and ansible.

yaml file:

```
    - name: Add a tenant using Json and Rest over ansible
      aci_rest:
        host: 10.42.0.82
        username: admin
        password: password
    
        method: post
        path: /api/mo/uni.json
    
        content:
          {
            "fvTenant": {
              "attributes": {
                "name": "customer-Test",
                "descr": "Customer Test"
              }
            }
          }
```

---

Error being experienced:

> ERROR! 'aci_rest' is not a valid attribute for a Play

The error appears to be in '/home/rancid/ansible/test.yaml': line 1, column 3, but may
be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

The offending line appears to be:

```
    - name: Add a tenant using Json and Rest over ansible
      ^ here
```

---

Ansible and python

```
rancid@~/ansible~~ansible --version
ansible 2.9.3
  config file = /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = [u'/home/rancid/.ansible/plugins/modules',                 u'/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
  ansible python module location = /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible
  executable location = /bin/ansible
  python version = 2.7.5 (default, Aug  7 2019, 00:51:29) [GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-        39)]
```

I tried to follow the documentation at
https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/scenario_guides/guide_aci.html

Comment: Could be an issue with your `test.yaml` file. The task itself looks to be fine.

Comment: after full uninstall on ansible and reinstall the error has changed to a module error. 
{"msg": "Could not find imported module support code for aci_tenant.  Looked for either ACIModule.py or aci.py"}

Answer (score 0):

reinstalled ansible and copied original yaml files from source cisco DEVNET